# Acceder a las propiedades de un JSON llamado con http post en Angular 4

Tags: angular4

resulta que estoy haciendo una solicitud post a una URL con el siguiente codigo

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './../user.service';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  username: string = '';
  password: string = '';

  results: object;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    if(this.userService.isValid()) {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
        return;
    }
  }

  login() {

    var body = {
     email : this.username,
     password: this.password
    };

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', body).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;

      console.log(data);

    });

  }



}
```

lo cual me devuelve lo siguiente

```
{
  "success":
    {
      "data":
        {
          "id":6,"name":"nthny20",
          "email":"nthny20@hotmail.com",
          "user_role_id":"1",
          "created_at":"2018-01-20 19:51:40",
          "updated_at":"2018-01-20 19:51:40",
          "token":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi"
      }
    }
  }
```

pero al intentar colocar `data.success.data.token` que es la propiedad a la cual quiero acceder, me manda error.

Comment: ¿en qué parte de tu código? no lo veo. ¿Podés [edit] y agregar la línea donde la estás usando y mostrar el error que te da?

Comment: prueba con : results = data.json()